# RegExp error: missing terminating ] for character class at offset 7

Tags: php

I am getting  stderr:

```
PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Compilation failed: missing terminating ] 
for character class at offset 7 in an php file.
```

My `$regex = '/[' . implode('', $alphabet) . ']{3,}$/S';`

where `$alphabet` is an array containing some random letters in each positions (`[0] -> R`, `[1] -> A` and so on)

and it throws the error in: `if(preg_match($regex, $value))` and  `$value` is a word.

Any ideas whats wrong?

Regards,
Espen

Comment: It works fine for me. How do you create your array `$alphabet`? My guess is your array contains a regex reserved character...

Comment: Can you show `$alphabet` please?

Comment: this is an example of the $alphabet. Randomly picked numbers:

Comment: alfabeth
(
    [0] => n
    [1] => m
    [2] => j
    [3] => k
    [4] => c
    [5] => m
    [6] => w
    [7] => m
    [8] => f
    [9] => j
    [10] => h
    [11] => z
    [12] => p
    [13] => j
    [14] => f
    [15] => g
    [16] => j
    [17] => r
    [18] => o
    [19] => z
    [20] => s
    [21] => t
    [22] => j
    [23] => u
    [24] => g
    [25] => s
    [26] => w
    [27] => r
    [28] => h
    [29] => r
    [30] => r
)

Comment: It create a random alphabet array based on this selection: $allLetters = array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z');

Comment: Mathieu, you had right. I had a table of 140 000 words, and 20 of them had special characters like '%' and '½' symbols. I have removed them, and it seems like it work. Thank everyone for your time helping me.

Answer (score 4):

add preg_quote() call around your alphabet... possibly you add some unsafe characters there, which result in character class being broken

```
$regex = '/[' . preg_quote(implode('', $alphabet)) . ']{3,}$/S';
```